# Ruby array access position in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
@product
```

returns a single record.  By relationship this product belongs to a slot

```
@slot = Slot.where(['id = ?', @product.slot_id]).first
```

what needs to be accessed is the position `x` in the array of all `@slots = Slot.order('id asc').all` so that I can identify or iterate over the following n slots as per [ruby array Class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html):

```
arr[x, n]
```

Comment: I am not understanding the question. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ slots will be an array of index positions 0 to last. @ product.slot_id has an index position and I'd like to extract that.

Comment: Not quite clearly understanding your question, but are you trying to access `@product.slot.position` (which seems to be x here) from `@slots` array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question there are many methods of accessing the index for an `Array` e.g.

```
 alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
 alphabet[0]
 #=> "a"
 alphabet.values_at(2,3,12)
 #=> ["c","d","m"]
 alphabet.index('r')
 #=> 17
 alphabet.fetch(15)
 #=> "p"
```

There are many more such as `#at`, `#find_index`, even `#rindex` which will look for the last occurance. If you need to iterate index's you can use `each_index` or `each_with_index`. Since your question does not truely explain the scenario all I can do is explain how to deal with `Array` indices. For a more pertinent answer please update your question to show both data and expected results.

Here is what I can gather from your question

```
@product = Product.find(some_id)
@slot = @product.slot
@slots = Slot.where("id > ?", @slot.id) #return all slots after the @product.slot
```

Comment: `index('r') is what I was looking for (and not evidenced in link published in the question.

Comment: @Jerome `find_index` and `index` (alias) are both documented in the link you posted

Answer (score 0):

If want to get the `Slot` for a given `Product` you can just do this:

```
slot = @product.slot
```

assuming you have your relationships well defined.